# Minimize the summation of two quadratic terms over an annulus

Tags: optimization, quadratics, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I'm attempting to solve the following problem in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & (x-x^0)^\intercal \Lambda (x-x^0) + (y-y^0)^\intercal \Lambda (y-y_0)\\ \text{subject to} & 1-\varepsilon \le x_i^2 + y_i^2 \le 1+\varepsilon \qquad \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}\end{array}$$

where $x^0, y^0$ and $\varepsilon$ are all known parameters and square matrix $\Lambda$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Clearly, if

$$\quad 1-\varepsilon \le (x^0_i)^2 + (y^0_i)^2 \le 1+\varepsilon$$

for $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$, then the optimal solution is $x = x^0, y=y^0$. But what if $x^0$ and $y^0$ do not satisfy the constraint? Is there still an analytical solution (explicit form) to this optimization problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The constraints are on $x$ and $y$, not $x^0$ and $y^0$.

Comment: Right, $x^0, y^0$ are parameters here. If the all the parameters happen to satisfy $1-\epsilon \le (x_i^0)^2 + (y_i^0)^2 \le 1+\epsilon$, then the problem is easy.

Comment: This is not a convex optimisation problem unless $\epsilon >1$.